# How can I make trigger from two different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

How can I make trigger to read from two separated attribute in two different tables and then 
calculate something .

this is the code I want to make but the mysql says it has problem

```
CREATE TRIGGER `fee_calculate` BEFORE INSERT ON `BookingRoom`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
SET NEW.fee = `Booking.Night_Qty` *  `Room.RoomPrice` ;
END
```

Comment: In Postgres, you would use a trigger function for that. I don't know the syntax to do that in MySQL.

Comment: Is `BookingRoom` an association table? If so you definitely want to do this as an `AFTER INSERT`, not a before. You will need to select the associated values from `Booking` and `Room`, respectively.

Comment: What does **Booking.Night_Qty** and **Room.RoomPrice** stands for?

Answer (score 0):

I Think It Should Help You

I made some assumptions:

1. I assumed you wanted to update the reorders table with a productID that matches the Products table. (you can do an insert but may run into PK issues depending on how you have your table set up).
2. I assumed that the reorder amount will be placed there.
3. I did NOT include transaction statements, I would recommend adding these so it's logged.

CREATE trigger updateprod
on Products
for update as
begin
declare @qtyonhand int,
@reorder int
if update(QtyonHand)
begin
select @qtyonhand = QtyonHand,@reorder = ReorderAmount from inserted
if @qtyonhand < @reorder
begin
update Reorders set ReorderAmount = @reorder, ReorderDate = getdate()
end
else if @qtyonhand >= @reorder
begin
delete from reorders where ProductID = ProductID
end
end
end